# setInterval is not working

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function:

```
function chk(){
   alert("Welcome");
}

window.onload = chk();
setInterval("chk();", 5000);
```

but it is not working but when I refresh the page it works for me. How can I fix that?

Comment: To be clear, you want an alert to popup on page load and *again* 5 seconds later? What exactly is not working?

Comment: window.onload must read: window.onload = chk;

Answer (score 7):

This works just fine for me.  Note the use of the function reference instead of calling the function and assigning the return value.  SetInterval need not use a string -- which forces an eval of the argument.  You can also use a function reference (or an anonymous function) as the argument.

```
function chk() {
    alert('checking');
}

window.onload = chk;

setInterval(chk,5000);
```

Comment: Yes, the function reference method of calling is preferred.

Comment: OP - Notice the lack of a parameter list on the function reference.
window.onload = chk(); would run the function, and set window.onload to whatever value is returned from the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the alert to display once, after 5 seconds, use:

```
function chk(){
   alert("Welcome");
}

setTimeout("chk()", 5000);
```

If you want the alert to appear every 5 seconds (extremely annoying, but there is other legitimate for setInterval)

```
function chk(){
   alert("Welcome");
}

setInterval("chk()", 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chk(){
   alert("Welcome");
}

window.onload = chk();
setInterval("chk();", 5000);
```

`window.onload` becomes `undefined` here -- `chk` doesn't return anything. And you need to rewrite your setInterval like this: `setInterval(chk, 5000);`